# In which cases does compiler create a new temporary local value while comparing two types?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

```
template <typename T> inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b) 
{ 
    return a < b ? b : a; 
}

inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b) 
{ 
    return std::strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a; 
} 

template <typename T> inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c);
}

int main () 
{ 
    const char* s1 = "frederic"; 
    const char* s2 = "anica"; 
    const char* s3 = "lucas"; 

    ::max(s1, s2, s3);
}
```

For the above code, the book (C++ Templates - Wesley) says:

> The problem is that if you call max() for three C-strings, the statement return max (max(a,b), c); becomes an error. This is because for C-strings, max(a,b) creates a new, temporary local value that may be returned by the function by reference.

Now, my question is that in which cases compiler automatically creates and returns temporary variables, and why (including this one)?

Oh! Does it mean that compiler creates a temporary variable for storing each value and then returns those compared temporary variables? Are there other cases too, in which this is done?

Comment: You should make your `const char*` overload have signature `const char * & max(const char * & a, const char * & b)` so it returns a reference to the original argument rather than a copy.

Comment: @Kerrek: you forgot a `const` before `&`.

Comment: @Mattieu: Yes, thanks! `const char * const & a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do it slowly:

```
::max(s1, s2, s3);
```

invokes `T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)` with `T` being `char const*`.

Within this method we have:

```
max(a,b)
```

which invokes `char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)`

```
max(max(a,b), c);
```

thus invokes `char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)` as well

And thus the dreaded part (if we rewrite):

```
template <typename T>
T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
  T result = max(max(a,b), c);
  return result;                 // reference to a temporary
}
```

Because `T` is `char const*` and `max(char const*, char const*)` returns a copy (of the pointer) and not a const reference to the pointer.

`gcc` helpfully diagnose the issue (see [ideone](http://ideone.com/x9YEp)):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘const T& max(const T&, const T&, const T&) [with T = const char*]’:
prog.cpp:27:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:18: warning: returning reference to temporary
```

With `18` being the `return max(....)` in the template and `27` being the invocation.

If you rewrite `max` to "hide" this temporary:

```
template <typename T> inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    T const& result = max (max(a,b), c);
    return result;
}
```

You will foil gcc's detection (see [ideone](http://ideone.com/wsAmk)), but this does not solve the issue. Clang would helpfully warn that `T const& result` is bound to a temporary.

The real problem is that `char const* max(char const*, char const*)` is returning a value so either all `max` should return by values or all `max` should take and return const references... if you wish to mix them up.

Comment: That's right, but there's more: the outer max would be safe if the things being passed to it were, and top definition were being called. What's really killer for the compiler to work out, and which could let it compile but with run-time errors, is the the inner max returns a temporary to the outer one. You have to think about the return value of the inner max as well as the outer one, which is what the book is actually trying to explain when it mentions `max(a,b)`.

Comment: @Nicholas: if you are talking about the statement `max(max(a,b), c)` then no. Nothing is wrong with it. The inner `max` returns a copy of the pointer and the outer `max` accepts both arguments by copy, so all is well. The trouble comes when mixing a `max` that deals with copies and a `max` that deals with references.

Comment: OK, I think we agree. I'm thinking about the reference outer max not handling the copied pointer.

Comment: @Nicholas: yes, this is why I named the temporary (`result`) to explicit where it was.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the overload `char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)` returns value, not reference. So temporary variable is created inside `template <typename T> inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)` and returned by reference, what is bad.

The problem is inconsistency between templated version and the overload. The overload should looks like:

```
inline char const* const& max (char const* const& a, char const* const& b)
```

Comment: The problem is, that the `const char*` version is not a specialization, but an overload.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: This solution is fine, [it](http://ideone.com/DUGbr) produces the same result as the original (incorrect) [version](http://ideone.com/x9YEp) as can be seen on the output. In both cases the overload is preferred to the template version, but in the latter (original) case, an unnamed temporary was generated right before the `return` call.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really anything to do with the compiler; this isn't one of those questions of how compilers make and optimise temporaries when it's discretionary for the implementation. What's going on is just a simple question of variable scope.

The second function down is returning by value, that is, there is a slot in memory which is destined to hold the return value of the function, and the value of a or b is copied into it. So, it returns a number which is a memory address, either the same address as is in a, or in b. Out of those two strings, one of the addresses is stored twice in memory in two different places.

So, the outer max in the third function: it's going to return by reference either c (which is safe), or the temporary (which is unsafe). The temporary is located just above the stack top in this case, and returning a reference to it is like returning a pointer, in this case to unsafe memory.

Either you could clean the whole thing up to use C-strings if that's the idea, or else fix up function 2 to return safe references.

Comment: I completely disagree with this analysis. `char const* result = max (max(a,b), c);` is completely fine, because it only involve copies at each step.

Comment: I agree that `char const* result = max (max(a,b), c);` is fine. I think I'm just making a total mess of explaining what I'm after. It's when the references are made to temporary copies that I'm trying to get at.

Comment: it's hard to talk about `max` when all functions are thusly called :( We thus agree on the issue, and I just didn't understood what you were pointing at :/

Answer (score 1):

The big problem here is actually the fact, that the `const char*` variant is unrelated to the template. This is a design problem. If you have a template, you shouldn't create unrelated overloads.

Now if you would create a specialization:

`template <> const char* max<const char*> (const char* a, const char* b);`

The compiler will tell you that is isn't compatible with the original template.

The correct version is actually:

`template <> const char * const & max<const char*> (const char* const &a, const char* const &b);`

Comment: actually, the conventional wisdom is to prefer overloads to specializations, to avoid the mess in determining which base template is actually selected for overload resolution. [See Sutter's take on it](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm). Anyway, the problem here is not about specialization versus overload, it could appear without templates, though would be more evident.